# RequireJS with jQuery and Module - Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

Here I have a simple requirejs setup. It consists of two dependencies - one being jQuery and another being my own module. I am recieving an error on myModule.init():

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myModule is not defined
```

HTML:

```
<script data-main="js/app.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

Code in app.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-3.1.1.min',
    }
});


// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'app/myModule'],
    function($, myModule) {
        myModule.init();
    });
```

Here is the Module that I created:

```
define('myModule', function () {
    return {
            init: function(){
                console.log('Hello World!');
            }
        }
});
```

Console Log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

[RequireJS Style Guide](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

Comment: Questions that are closed and edited go into the reopen queue and are eventually reopened if they've been edited to remove all issues. Reposting your question to work around closure is not an acceptable use of the site.

Comment: @Louis: Given that the earlier question has now been deleted, while this one has been answered, I think the dupe closure should be undone. Yes, the OP should've edited their original question instead of reposting it, but that's something neither we nor they can really fix any more at this point.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Found a duplicate that deals module naming, which is the one visible issue in the code presented by the OP. I've edited the duplicate link accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't supply a name to your module.

```
// app/myModule.js
define(function () {
    return {
            init: function(){
                console.log('Hello World!');
            }
        }
});
```

If you feel you need to, make it match what you are "requiring",  but this is more work and you should avoid it (let requirejs optimization tool do this for you):

```
// app/myModule.js
define("app/MyModule", function () {
    return {
            init: function(){
                console.log('Hello World!');
            }
        }
});
```